# how to avoid this very long if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I am still learning javascript, and am always looking for ways to make my code better. I wrote this **very long** if else statement. I am wondering if there is a simpler way to accomplish this. This code used [jquery transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) to animate rotaions. Basically when a user clicks a link the navigation rotates the clicked linked to the top position. The navigation is positioned in a circle.

```
var rotation = 0;
$('nav ul li a').bind('click', function () {
    'use strict';
    var item = $(this).parent();
    var itemI = item.index();
    var navAll = $(this).parents('ul');
    var pos0 = (rotation === 0);
    var pos1 = (rotation === 90);
    var pos2 = (rotation === 180);
    var pos3 = (rotation === 270);
    var item0 = (itemI === 0);
    var item1 = (itemI === 1);
    var item2 = (itemI === 2);
    var item3 = (itemI === 3);
    //------------------pos0 = 0----------------------------
    if (pos0 && item0) {
        //do nothing 0
    } else if (pos0 && item1) {
        navAll.transition({
            rotate: '-=90deg'
        });
        $('nav ul li a').transition({
            rotate: '90deg'
        });
        rotation = 270;
    } else if (pos0 && item2) {
        navAll.transition({
            rotate: '-=180deg'
        });
        $('nav ul li a').transition({
            rotate: '180deg'
        });
        rotation = 180;
    } else if (pos0 && item3) {
        navAll.transition({
            rotate: '+=90deg'
        });
        $('nav ul li a').transition({
            rotate: '-90deg'
        });
        rotation = 90;
    }
    //------------------pos1 = 90----------------------------
    else if (pos1 && item0) {
        navAll.transition({
            rotate: '0deg'
        });
        $('nav ul li a').transition({
            rotate: '0deg'
        });
        rotation = 0;
    } else if (pos1 && item1) {
        navAll.transition({
            rotate: '-90deg'
        });
        $('nav ul li a').transition({
            rotate: '90deg'
        });
        rotation = 270;
    } else if (pos1 && item2) {
        navAll.transition({
            rotate: '+=90deg'
        });
        $('nav ul li a').transition({
            rotate: '-180deg'
        });
        rotation = 180;
    } else if (pos1 && item3) {
        //do nothing 90
    }
    //------------------pos2 = 180----------------------------
    else if (pos2 && item0) {
        navAll.transition({
            rotate: '0deg'
        });
        $('nav ul li a').transition({
            rotate: '0deg'
        });
        rotation = 0;
    } else if (pos2 && item1) {
        navAll.transition({
            rotate: '-90deg'
        });
        $('nav ul li a').transition({
            rotate: '90deg'
        });
        rotation = 270;
    } else if (pos2 && item2) {
        //do nothing
        rotation = 180;
    } else if (pos2 && item3) {
        navAll.transition({
            rotate: '-=90deg'
        });
        $('nav ul li a').transition({
            rotate: '-90deg'
        });
        rotation = 90;
    }
    //------------------pos3 = 270----------------------------
    else if (pos3 && item0) {
        navAll.transition({
            rotate: '0deg'
        });
        $('nav ul li a').transition({
            rotate: '0deg'
        });
        rotation = 0;
    } else if (pos3 && item1) {
        //do nothing
    } else if (pos3 && item2) {
        navAll.transition({
            rotate: '-=90deg'
        });
        $('nav ul li a').transition({
            rotate: '180deg'
        });
        rotation = 180;
    } else if (pos3 && item3) {
        navAll.transition({
            rotate: '-=180deg'
        });
        $('nav ul li a').transition({
            rotate: '-90deg'
        });
        rotation = 90;
    }
});
```

Comment: This question should belong to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I suggest the first thing you could do is indent your code, because it's extremely hard to read as it appears now.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Thanks I didn't know code review existed, thats exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/RXYCP/)**

```
condition = rotation + "_" + itemI 

switch(condition)
{
   case "0_0":
        //your code
        break;
   case "90_0":
        //your code
        break;

   //Similarly you can add all cases.
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about using a switch statement, but I don't fully understand how it can be applied here. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I have added live demo for your understanding and also adding link for understanding and using switch.

Comment: took me a while but I got it to work, thank you. Pretty elegant solution. I didn't think of concatenating the variables.

Answer (score 0):

this might shorten the code.

create a 2d array with keys of rotation and itemI and a value of the combinations resulting deg val

then just access the array and run your commands as follows

```
if(degVal[rotation][itemI]<0)
    rotateSign = '-';
else
    rotateSign = '+';

navAll.transition({rotate: rotateSign+'='+degVal[rotation][itemI]+'deg'});
$('nav ul li a').transition({rotate: degVal[rotation][itemI]+'deg'});
rotation = degVal[rotation][itemI];
```